# DB2 SQL statement is running super slow only within BEGIN END block

Tags: sql, performance, db2, query-optimization

I have a big SQL script which contains a BEGIN-END block which consist in rebuild
The problem is when I run each statement individually, the statements are running OK
But when I put the statements in the block the performance becomes horrible (from ~1M rows read/s to 1000 rows read/s)

My block looks like this :

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE i BIGINT;
  --some JOIN/UPDATE statements
  --count lines
  WHILE(lines>0) DO
    --some joins that rebuild a hierarchy
    --count lines again
  END WHILE
END
```

The statement running slow are the JOIN within the while loop.
When I cut this statement and put the first JOINs outside the BEGIN-END everything is running OK

```
--some JOIN/UPDATE statements
BEGIN
  DECLARE i BIGINT;
  --count lines
  WHILE(lines>0) DO
    --some joins that rebuild a hierarchy
    --count lines again
  END WHILE
END
```

The above statement got good performance
I just would like to know why the fact of pulling off those JOIN/UPDATE statements of the block would affect performance like that ?

Thank you,

Comment: Optimize the query that is performing poorly. Use an Index-Advisor or query-optimizer tools available in toolsets such as IBM Data Studio. If you need to do expensive joins inside a while loop, then your code may be badly designed. Consider different approaches.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Although, the query runs fine when I move outside of the block some statements. I just do not understand the reason of that behavior. As I said, the row read speed tumbles down for no reason when inside... Idk why since it is the exact same statement...

Comment: Compare the access plans in either case.

Comment: Do you need to use a loop? Could your code not be completed in a single statement (maybe using recursion if needed)?